# Which SE site is appropriate for questions about Markdown?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, markdown

Which SE site is appropriate for questions about Markdown standard, its evolution, its variants, etc.?

My question is not really about a precise code question involving Markdown (if so, it might fit in Stack Overflow).

Comment: there could even be a markdown.SE site (similar to tex.SE) given the richness of versions, implementations etc.

Answer (score 2):

As a tool commonly used in writing and formatting texts, questions about markdown are on topic on our Writer's site.

> [**Writers Stack Exchange**](https://writers.stackexchange.com)
>   <sup>*Q&A site for anybody interested in the craft of professional writing, editing, and publishing.*</sup>

Comment: According to [this answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bCrp.jpg) of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301375/295738), it seems that some other websites could fit (of course, after looking at the "on-topic" page).

Comment: After having looked at Writers.SE, I think it's more dedicated (looking at most questions there) to content (novel questions, how to choose titles, [fiction writing](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/30379/how-to-handle-a-characters-failure)) and much less about technical questions about markdown: https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/markdown