# Which SE site has the most questions associated with a given [tag]?

Tags: support, tags, stack-exchange, data-explorer

Is it possible to do a list of SE sites sorted by the highest appearance of questions with a given tag? For example `[markdown]`?

Something like:

- Stack Overflow 3970 questions
- ...
- TeX 119 questions

I was thinking about running a script looping on all sites:

```
for site in ['tex', 'math', 'meta', ...]
   open URL '<site>.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/markdown'
   get the number "xxx questions tagged"
```

but I can imagine there's a more clever solution.

Comment: I assume you can craft something from those SEDE queries: [user reputation accross sites](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/642699/user-reputation-across-sites) and [Q by tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/726674/q-by-tag)

Comment: A first draft [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/728428/number-of-question-by-site-filtered-by-tag), I was unable to use a variable for the tag, so you'll have to edit the query and then order the resulting table.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/728486/tag-uses-per-site?tagname=markdown#results) is the SEDE query you're looking for: [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown) is used the most on Stack Overflow.

[image]

Note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning, so the results might be a bit stale, but overall it gives a good impression.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Here is the full CSV (can you read it or is it limited to myself?): http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/csv/906257

Comment: @Basj I can read it but I wonder why it isn’t sorted?!

Comment: [Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bCrp.jpg) of the 16 first sites in decreasing order.

Comment: Since the question is oriented to finding the top result(s), updating the answer with sorting would be useful. The query change is trivial - just add `order by tagcount DESC` after/below `from #results`.

Comment: @Marcus thanks, I've also updated it to [add the correct site names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359795/295232). It's good to revisit old queries once in a while :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the global [Filtered Questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters) page for this:

[image: just questions with the coffee tag, on just these sites]

Just type in the specific tag you want to see, and select the "Just these sites" option. The sites with the most questions with that tag will be shown first with a count of how many questions (which is unfortunately cut off a little sometimes). Note: the main tag must match, not a synonym.

What's nice about this method is that the text box will suggest tags that match what you're typing.